# How to use prepared statements with GROUP BY?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have a prepared statement that I'm trying to run but when when it binds the parameters I end up with

```
GROUP BY "Column"
```

instead of

```
GROUP BY Column
```

Which ends with results that say

```
"Column" | 2
"Column" | 3
```

Instead of taking the values from column and substituting them. The query runs perfectly when I hard code it, it's only when I prepare and bind that it starts to get wonky.

EDIT: The whole query

```
$sql = "SELECT ?, COUNT(?) FROM (
            SELECT ? FROM keno
            WHERE Date = '7/21/2014'
            ORDER BY `Game Number` ASC
            LIMIT ?
        ) as temp_table
        GROUP BY ?
        ORDER BY ? ASC";
```

And the binding

```
$current_position = "One";
$limit = $i + 1 //Inside a for loop
$qry->bind_param("sssiss", $current_position, $current_position, $current_position, $limit, $current_position, $current_position)
```

Comment: Care to share the whole query?

Comment: @Machavity sure one second

Comment: @Machavity let me know if you need more

Comment: You can only parameterize *values*, not column names, table names, keywords, etc.

Comment: You're dynamically setting the columns to be selected??

Comment: You can do this `$column="column_x";` then `SELECT $column` but not `SELECT ?` - It needs to know "ahead" of time as to what it needs to look for.

Comment: Are you using Column as the reserved Keyword that it is, or as the name for one of your columns?